# Azure Sql FireWall rule to allow azure services and resources to access this server using command line

Tags: sql-server, azure

Is there a way to enable or disable the following [using the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/server/firewall-rule?view=azure-cli-latest).

[image: Azure Sql Server Filewall Rule]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by creating a firewall rule with “0.0.0.0” as both start and end IP address.

Comment: Ok, but will this not open doors for everyone and anyone?

Comment: Oh man, its working. I used the following command, it worked.
az sql server firewall-rule create --resource-group rgName --server sqlServerName --name TrialFirewallRule --start-ip-address 0.0.0.0 --end-ip-address 0.0.0.0
And used the following to make it No
az sql server firewall-rule delete --resource-group rgName --server sqlServerName --name TrialFirewallRule

Comment: No, for that you have to do “0.0.0.0” to “255.255.255.255”.